# expo ios applinks crashed if app is already opened in background

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I created my app using expo and I have somewhat successfully created applinks with the following in app.json. Its a testflight build so I dont have any stack trace. I also dont have any code to handle the link because in expo it is just a normal page (post.js). Page is navigated automatically by expo

```
"ios": {
        "associatedDomains": ["applinks:mydomain.net"],
        "supportsTablet": true,
        "bundleIdentifier": "com.mydomain",
        "buildNumber": "7",
        "runtimeVersion": {
            "policy": "sdkVersion"
        }
    }
```

I also have a valid AASA file hosted.

When I click on a link in whatsapp with link mydomain.net/post?id=6 my app will launch and navigate to the correct page. Now when I switch back to whatsapp without killing my app and still in background, and click the link again, my app crashed.

I have no idea how to debug this and can't find any similar case around. Hope someone with similar experience can share what to look out for.

Comment: You've not provided enough information to help you. Do you have a stack trace and can you post the link handling code?

Comment: Its a testflight build so I dont have any stack trace. I also dont have any code to handle the link because in expo it is just a normal page (post.js). Page is navigated automatically by expo.